# Using rowDrag with dndSource in ag-grid

Tags: angular, typescript, drag-and-drop, ag-grid

Is it possible to use "rowDrag" and "dndSource=true" together?

As I understand, to achieve to drag & drop outside the grid, I have to set the "dndSource=true". But I can't seem to use it when "rowDrag" is active.

Comment: Did you find an answer to this?

Answer (score 1):

Please Follow link below :  
[Ag-grid Reference: Column Properties](https://ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-column-properties/)

Link Mentioned below some properties for row drag :

1. rowDrag - Boolean
2. dndSource - Boolean

Also check below link for row drag & drop : 
[javascript grid row dragging](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-row-dragging/)

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. The problem I'm facing is that I can't use rowDrag and dndSource together if I declare them. Means there will be two drag buttons with different effect. Basically, I want to achieve the "rowDrag" with the possibility to drop outside the grid with custom data but want to keep the features of "rowDrag".

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to have dndSource and row dragging at the same time.  The trick is to use `rowDragEntireRow` this will hide the row dragging button and allow you to drag the row by clicking anywhere on it.

you column definition should set `dndSource` and set `rowDragEntireRow` on the grid

```
<AgGridReact
    ref={rightGridRef}
    onGridReady={(event) => {
      setRightGridReady(true)
      event.api.sizeColumnsToFit()
    }}
    rowDragManaged={true}
    rowDragEntireRow={true}
    columnDefs={[
      {headerName: "", dndSource: true, width: 30, suppressMenu: true},
      {headerName: "Pivot By", field: 'name', suppressMenu: true}
    ]}
    rowData={selected.map((item) => {return {name: item}})}
    getRowNodeId={(data) => data.name}
/>
```

see the section on Entire Row Dragging https://www.ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/row-dragging/